# Image text aligned left, inside div

Tags: css, html

I have an image with text aligned to the left of it. Both the image and text is sitting inside a div that I have styled to look like a red bubble in the background of the post. The bubble only goes as far as the text and not the image (the image goes down much farther than the text), causing the image to break into other posts. How do I make this div the correct size that can fit anything i put into it (in this case the image)?

```
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sederu/CzNr6/
```

Comment: Please add some code as those who want to help cannot without your code.

Comment: Code please, HTML/CSS/JS, or better yet a jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sederu/CzNr6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your .post-bubble rule.

```
div.post-bubble {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #e17474;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CzNr6/1/)**

Comment: Bro, you rock! Worked like a charm!

Comment: FYI you should also work on removing the inline CSS and updating deprecated syntax like `align="right"` with either `float:right` or `text-align:right`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution and reccomendation, I will be sure to change that! Thanks!

Comment: I'd go with a class (or classes) over IDs here.

Comment: this is what i did and its not working: '<img class="book-review" src="images/not_a_fan.jpg"> and my css was: img.book-review { text-align: left}

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content to allow anything inside of it, give it `overflow:auto`.

If you want the bubble to extend so that it also covers the `img` tag, however, give `.post-bubble` a height:

```
div.post-bubble {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #e17474;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The reason why the image extends farther than the div is because the `img` is taken out of the flow of the page, i.e. no longer being a block element, when you declare `align:right`.

Answer (score 1):

either add `overflow:auto;` to your post-bubble div or define a height to the post-bubble div eg.. `height: 600px;` covers it nicely..

Answer (score 0):

On div tag do a display:block in css

Comment: Remove padding and add margin, if you have any

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to force element to self-clear its children.

```
div.post-bubble:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
```

You can also create a specific class for other elements in your project/projects like:

```
.clear-children:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
```

And add this class (.clear-children, without :after)  to every element with floated children.

http://jsfiddle.net/CzNr6/4/